# tkinter grid layout and label hight

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have an entry form with (among other widgets) an `Entry` widget to enter some value and a `Listbox` to show the valid values entered so far. Below the `Entry` widget I show a validation message (empty when value is valid or error description if not) along with a big symbol (`''` for error and `''` for valid).

The following is a minimal example to simulate valid and invalid entries by clicking the button:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N)
tk.Listbox(root, height=10).grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky=tk.N)

label = tk.Label(root)
label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.N)

symbol = tk.Label(root, font='Arial 72 bold')
symbol.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.S)

def toggle():
    n = 0 if len(label['text']) > 10 else 3
    label['text'] = '\n'.join([f'error message line {i}' for i in range(n)])
    symbol['text'] = '' if n else ''
        
tk.Button(root, text='toggle message', command=toggle).grid(column=0, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

The symbol moves down when the error message becomes longer although there's still plenty of space between the bottom of the last error message line and the top of the  symbol. The reason is that the maximum character hight of the 72 pt font could use this extra space (can be easyly verified by inserting a full hight vertical line [`︳`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FE33) before the symbol.

Apart from decreasing the symbol font size (which I don't want) or increasing the total hight reserved for the message and the symbol (which I can't) I see the only workaround in replacing the character symbol by an image symbol where the strokes extend over the full image hight.

So my question is: **how to keep the button in place when the message line hight changes?** Is it possible to somehow overlap the symbol and the message (knowing that the symbol character strokes don't fill the full font hight). I tried negative paddings but tkinter does not allow that. I also want to stick with the `grid` layout manager.

Comment: Use a canvas with `create_text()`

Comment: Since you're limiting the size of the label to three lines of text, have you tried setting the initial height of the label to 3?

Comment: Also, if you resize the window, what do you expect to happen? Does the symbol stay stuck immediately above the button, immediately below the label, or centered in the space between the button and label?

Comment: @BryanOakley: 3 lines is just an example, in reality the message is an error message that comes from different sources und can have different length, I can't exclude that it may be even longer than 3 lines. But yes - setting the height in accordance with an assumed maximum message length maybe an easier solution (thanks a lot, sometimes one doesn't think about the obvious solutions :)). I didn't care about resizing, i.e. the user is not meant to resize the window.

Comment: As a user, there's few things I mind more frustrating than not being able to resize a window. Tkinter is very good at making it easy to create resizable UIs. If you design with that in mind, the problem becomes much easier to solve. What do you expect the user to do if there are more messages than will fit and they can't see them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the second row resize to adapt to the window height and setting `grid_propagate` to False, then the button stays in place:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N)
tk.Listbox(root, height=10).grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky=tk.N)

root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)  # make second row resize to fit window height 
label = tk.Label(root)
label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.N)

symbol = tk.Label(root, font='Arial 72 bold')
symbol.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.S)

def toggle():
    n = 0 if len(label['text']) > 10 else 3
    label['text'] = '\n'.join([f'error message line {i}' for i in range(n)])
    symbol['text'] = '' if n else ''

tk.Button(root, text='toggle message', command=toggle).grid(column=0, row=3)
root.update_idletasks()
root.grid_propagate(False)  # disable window resizing when its children change size
root.mainloop()
```

Note that if the error message is very long, the symbol will not be visible.

Comment: This is exacly what I need, I didn't know [`grid_propagate`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid-methods.html). Thanks a lot.

Comment: `grid_propagate` is almost never the right solution. It will usually make the UI not be responsive to changes in window size, and differences on other platforms such as different default fonts.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I am aware that this is not ideal, but by doing `root.update_idletasks()` before `root.grid_propagate(False)`, the window size is at least adapted to its initial content.